# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. lib/main.dart:26 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing that error because `http.get` requires a Uri and not a String.

Try pass `Uri.parse(apiUrl)` instead of `apiUrl`

Comment: I answered it a min earlier. :)

Comment: @TirthPatel i was writing and i didn't see it, sorry

Comment: that's alright. we're cool.

Answer (score 1):

`http.get` requires a `Uri`, not a `String`. Use `Uri.parse` method to create a `Uri`.

```dart
await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
```